# Where to find the Dll's after installing Crystal reports version 12.0 into my system?

Tags: crystal-reports-2008

I had installed a crystal report 2008 version 12.0 runtime on my system. I am currently using  visual studio 2008. Can anyone out there tell me where can i find the dlls like crystaldecisions.shared , crystaldecisions.web etc under this version..

regards

Midhun

Answer (score 0):

If they're not somewhere in the application's install directory, then they must be in `WINDOWS/system32`. (I assume that folder is actually called `system64` on 64 bits versions of Windows.)

Answer (score 0):

Most probably these dlls will be in global assembly cache. For windows it can be seen under C:\WINDOWS\assembly, provided that windows is installed in c: drive